# How can I capture traffic for a daemon listening on a cloned loopback IP address?

Tags: networking, freebsd, packet-capture, loopback, pcap

I have a daemon listening on a virtual IP address attached to a cloned loopback interface (`lo1`) on FreeBSD 11.x.

Inbound traffic for that daemon could arrive on several different physical interfaces, however running `tcpdump` on loopback only shows traffic that also *originates* from the loopback, and won't show traffic that is routed there from the outside.    (NB: even for that to work you have to monitor the original `lo0` i/f, not the cloned one).

Is there any way that I capture traffic destined for that daemon on the loopback without having to monitor each physical port separately?

Post processing of pcaps with `tcpmerge` would be unwieldy, and there's also some special capture code running that is neither amenable to offline merging nor re-writing to handle multiple interfaces at the same time.

Comment: This (2007) could maybe be related: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=112612

Comment: @A.B yup, I'm aware of that one, thanks :)